# Any suggestions for getting a thick (almost chewy) body and mouthfeel when brewing a Milk Stout?

Tags: all-grain, stout, imperial, body

I am obsessed with the thick body, sweet style stouts (Milk Stouts, Russian Imperial Stouts Bourbon Barrel Stouts, etc.), think Dragon's Milk, Old Rasputin, Lakewood's Temptress. While I have attempted to brew my own a handful of times, they always come out with thin and light bodied, which I am NOT a fan of. I thought Maltodextrin would be the golden ticket and tried adding it with priming sugar during racking, but the brew is still too thin for my liking.

I am brewing all grain with a 10 gal capacity. Any suggestions? Please help!

Comment: Mash temperature can play a significant role. Higher temperatures tend to yield more body. This article has a good explanation [link](http://beersmith.com/blog/2012/12/20/mash-temperature-and-beer-body-in-all-grain-brewing/)

Comment: Over-carbonation can make a beer feel thin. I targeted 2.3 volumes for my last RIS, and it came out great. You might want to go lower than that for a lighter-bodied beer like a milk stout.

Answer (score 12):

Some things I can think of to increase body:

- Milk stouts use lactose, or milk sugar, to increase perceived body and sweetness. Lactose is unfermentable by yeast and so passes to the finished beer.
- Dextrin malt (CaraPils, CaraFoam) will impart a nice bit of body without adding crystal-malt-flavor (something I don't like in stouts).
- Mash high. Try 156°+ for a single-infusion mash. This will favor creation of dextrins, which can increase body, over fermentable extract.
- Wheat, raw or malted, can add body-increasing proteins to wort and beer. Oats contribute a characteristic fullness. Raw barley (usually flaked) could be good too. Experiment with some different grains.
- Try upping the ABV. Alcohol can boost the perceived body. Just make sure to condition longer to take the edge off.

Comment: What he said. with one addition: specialty grains add unfermentable sugars to the beer and that adds mouthfeel.

Answer (score 2):

Franklin P Combs and Atron Seige are completely correct with their suggestions. Google Brewers Best Milk Stout recipe. It's my favorite extract recipe and is nice and thick. It also uses lactose and maltodextrin.

---

The ingredients for Brewer's Best Milk Stout are:

```
Fermentables
  3.3 lb. Special Dark LME
  3.3 lb. Light LME
  .5 lb. Lactose
  .5 lb. Maltodextrin

Specialty Grains
  8 oz. Caramel 120L
  4 oz. Roasted Barley
  4 oz. Dark Chocolate

Hops
  .5 oz. GR Magnum
  .5 oz. Cluster
```